# Why is the Unit of Work pattern considered fast and efficient when working with an ORM?

Tags: rdbms, unit-of-work

In working with [Doctrine 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29#History) I came across the following paragraph.

> In fact, since Doctrine is aware of all your managed entities, when
>   you call theflush() method, it calculates an overall changeset and
>   executes the most efficient query/queries possible. For example, if
>   you persist a total of 100 Product objects and then subsequently call
>   flush(), Doctrine will create a single prepared statement and re-use
>   it for each insert. This pattern is called Unit of Work, and it's used
>   because it's fast and efficient

I am not up to speed on relational databases and [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) theory so I was wondering why is the [Unit Of Work pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)  considered fast and efficient?

Answer (score 5):

One reason the Unit Of Work pattern can be efficient, as the paragraph states, is because it can batch several operations and reuse resources.

Using Unit of Work provides a context that can contain several operations into a single transaction that might otherwise be difficult to operate on together.

Also, not only can the Unit of Work use a single prepared statement for efficiency, but it may also be able to submit many inserts or updates to the database in a single call - if the database driver supports it - rather than executing each insert or update individually.

Answer (score -1):

I think that one uses the unit of work pattern with ORMs because it is a pattern that is easy to translate from your code to database transactions as both have the same logical boundaries. You can test your unit of work without a database.

Speed and efficiency is really an implementation detail.